# Perl script - como calcular frequências com base no tamanho das sequências?

Tags: perl

Eu tenho este código em perl para calcular a contagem de di-peptídeos nas minhas sequências (sao 400 combinacoes, por examplo AA, AC, AD, AE...). Porém quero calcular a frequência destas contagens, para isso so preciso dividir a contagem pelo tamanho de cada sequência (length), porém tentei de diversas formas e nao consegui fazer o cálculo correto.
Meu script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my @amino=qw/A C D E F G H I K L M N P Q R S T V W Y/;
my @comb=();

foreach my $a (@amino){
    foreach my $b (@amino){
                push (@comb,$a.$b)
        }
}
my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "myfile.fasta" , '-format' => 'Fasta');
while ( my $seq= $in->next_seq ) {
my @dipeps=($seq->seq()=~/(?=(.{2}))/g);
my %di_count=();
$di_count{$_}++ for @dipeps;
print $seq->id();
map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0}sort @comb;
print "\n";
}
```

Eu tentei:

```
map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0}sort @comb/length;

map{exists $di_count{$_}?print " ",$di_count{$_}:print " ",0/length}sort @comb;
```

Mas nao resultou no esperado.
Ou preciso calcular o tamanho das sequências antes e definir antes? Sugestoes?

Comment: cuidado que `lenght` sozinho dá o comprimento de `$_` no teu caso o comprimento de combinação (=2).

Answer (score 0):

Em vez do map (que fica neste caso um pouco confuso) propunha:

```
$len=scalar @dipeps;
for(sort keys %di_count){
   print " ",$di_count{$_}/$len}
```

(não testado)

Comment: nao deu certo, os resultados ficam incorretos.